# OS X Yosemite 10.10 keeps crashing on usb WiMax eject/unplug

Tags: crash, usb, wimax

My OS X Yosemite 10.10 keeps getting crashed on USB WiMax eject/unplug. It was working fine with Mavericks. After upgrade whenever I eject or unplug USB WiMax devices, Yosemite crashes and restart showing the error screen in different languages

Error I am getting is called kernel panic. "Your computer restarted because of a problem. Press any key or......"

MacBook Specs:

MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012) Intel Based
Processor: 2.5 GHz Intel Core i5
Memory: 4 GB 1600 MHz DDR3

Any fix for this???

```
*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff8002c1e80a): Kernel trap at 0xffffff800305bc54, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0xffffff806d24f000, CR3: 0x0000000005a19000, CR4: 0x00000000001626e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0xffffff7f839bcf58, RCX: 0x00000000035d0000, RDX: 0xffffff800daf8140
RSP: 0xffffff809c89be70, RBP: 0xffffff809c89be80, RSI: 0xffffff7f839bcf58, RDI: 0xffffff806d24f000
R8:  0x0000000000000004, R9:  0xffffff800f20cd50, R10: 0x0000006cf917b392, R11: 0x0000006cf87f6395
R12: 0x0000000000000000, R13: 0xffffff8003310688, R14: 0xffffff806d24f000, R15: 0xffffff7f839b9cfc
RFL: 0x0000000000010286, RIP: 0xffffff800305bc54, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0xffffff806d24f000, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x0

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff809c89bb20 : 0xffffff8002b3a811 
0xffffff809c89bba0 : 0xffffff8002c1e80a 
0xffffff809c89bd60 : 0xffffff8002c3a443 
0xffffff809c89bd80 : 0xffffff800305bc54 
0xffffff809c89be80 : 0xffffff7f839b9d13 
0xffffff809c89bea0 : 0xffffff80030db3cd 
0xffffff809c89bf00 : 0xffffff8002b6be13 
0xffffff809c89bfb0 : 0xffffff8002c192c7 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDCECMData(4.2.2b5)[762A4700-2305-3989-8E9B-D107BDB0A47E]@0xffffff7f839b8000->0xffffff7f839bcfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily(3.2)[247581D8-DFC5-3AAE-B079-3D13F5514C2B]@0xffffff7f836fd000


dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily(705.4.14)[E15E9DC8-410F-3612-8371-E5FECD939E0D]@0xffffff7f8373c000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
14A389

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0: Fri Sep 19 00:26:44 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2782.1.97~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 89E10306-BC78-3A3B-955C-7C4922577E61
Kernel slide:     0x0000000002800000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8002a00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8002900000
System model name: MacBookPro9,2 (Mac-6F01561E16C75D06)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 468025722807
last loaded kext at 110284838526: com.apple.filesystems.cd9660  1.4.4 (addr 0xffffff7f848e5000, size 40960)
last unloaded kext at 233663916476: com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.20.24 (addr 0xffffff7f845b3000, size 2043904)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.filesystems.cd9660    1.4.4
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.0f10
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.14.37
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDCECMData 4.2.2b5
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   266.5
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   266.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.4.12
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.10
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.0.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.0f10
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC    4.2.2b5
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.5
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.0
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.6.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.6.5
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.2b3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.0.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   900.19.8
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.7.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 266.5
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   200.6
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDCECMControl  4.2.2b5
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    156.4
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.7.21
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.0f10
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.0f10
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 266.5
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 266.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.8.0d49
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 245.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.0
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 4.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   700.52
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.6
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 389.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
Model: MacBookPro9,2, BootROM MBP91.00D3.B08, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.5 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 2.2f44
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333235533643465238432D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333235533643465238432D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xF5), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.124.12.8)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.0f10 14890, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Network Service: WiMAX USB Card, Ethernet, en3
Serial ATA Device: TOSHIBA MK5065GSXF, 500.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-8A8
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: WiMAX USB Card
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: USB OPTICAL MOUSE
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 25.1
```

Comment: This is off-topic for this site.

Comment: can you share your crashlog please

Comment: crash log report added

Comment: I have the same problem. I reported to Apple. Still no luck

Comment: Hi Ayon, is it the same problem with the same device? also: have you reported a bug to apple about the same

Comment: Hi Ayon, I'm not sure if this is fixable by anyone but apple :( but i was able to reduce the occurrence rate by doing the following:
1) report to apple 
2) reset permission via disk utilities http://support.apple.com/en-us/ht2963
3) pram reset

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same problem. Also using a laCie external hard drive with thunderbolt. The only solution I found is to do a safe boot (hold down the shift key while rebooting -- it will take several minutes to boot). Then I turn off the wifi and restart. Back to normal. Until I try to eject again!